# Compiling simple openCV project

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, g++

Attempting to compile a very simple program to test out my recent installation of OpenCV 3.2.0. My program `opencvtest.cpp` is in a folder called `cpp`, which also holds the `opencv-3.2.0` installation directory.

Here's my program.

```
//Include file for every supported OpenCV function
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  cv::Mat img = cv::imread( argv[1], -1 );

  if( img.empty() ) return -1;

  cv::namedWindow( "Example 2-1", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::imshow( "Example 2-1", img );
  cv::waitKey( 0 );
  cv::destroyWindow( "Example 2-1" );

  return 0;
}
```

Below I've included the call to pkg-config to show what parameters I'm using, and my actual g++ command to try and compile my file.

```
asif.ahmed:~/cpp $ pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui

asif.ahmed:~/cpp $ g++  opencvtest.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -o main
opencvtest.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Can anyone else suggest anything to get this to compile? I don't have a great grasp of command line compiling C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check path to `opencv.hpp` (is it really `/usr/include/opencv2/opencv2/opencv.hpp`?) - If you use `-I/usr/include/opencv2` perhaps you need `#include "opencv.hpp"` instead of `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`, or better use `-I/usr/include/` and `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`

Comment: I have /Users/asif.ahmed/cpp/opencv-3.2.0/include/opencv and a /Users/asif.ahmed/cpp/opencv-3.2.0/include/opencv2 directories, but the's no /usr/include/opencv2 or /usr/include/opencv directory. Can I just copy these directories into /usr/include?

Comment: no copy needed, just add (replace `-I/usr/include/opencv2`) one more option for compiler `-I/Users/asif.ahmed/cpp/opencv-3.2.0/include/`

Comment: Unfortunately compiling with the command `g++ opencvtest.cpp -o hello -I/Users/asif.ahmed/cpp/opencv-3.2.0/include/` still returns a `fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp' file not found` on my header

Comment: @Asif I suppose you should add more directories with `-I`. Look where `opencv_modules.hpp` is located, e.g. it can be `-I/Users/asif.ahmed/cpp/opencv-3.2.0/build/include/opencv2` or something like that